# Run a Java class in the terminal with AppleScript

Tags: java, macos, terminal, applescript

I have a java class named Adventure.class.
I have an AppleScript app named Adventure.
I am trying to make the Adventure app run Adventure.class in the Terminal on a mac.
Basically, I am trying to make it where a folder is downloadable, and inside is the app and a folder labeled "files".  Inside of files is a bin folder, and inside of that is the class file.  The Adventure.app is in the main directory, with the files folder.
Here is my AppleScript so far.

```
set filepath to POSIX path of (path to me)
set newpath to text 1 thru ((offset of "Adventure.app" in filepath) - 1) of filepath
do shell script "java " & newpath & "files/bin/Adventure"
```

Anyway, it's throwing this error:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: /Users/Russell/Documents/Adventure/files/bin/Adventure (wrong name: Adventure)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(ClassLoader.java:631)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:615)
at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:141)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:283)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(URLClassLoader.java:58)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:197)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
```

I can usually launch the class by typing `java Adventure` in the Terminal when I'm at the right folder.  However, I can't navigate to that folder in AppleScript, because it doesn't stay at that folder when you do the next line.  Any help would be appreciated :)

Comment: try using classpath argument set to the folder that contains your .class file. i.e. "java -classpath " & newpath & "files/bin Adventure"

Answer (score 0):

You can combine a "cd" command to set the path of the shell script. For example here I cd to the desktop and then get a list of files...

```
set desktopFolder to path to desktop
do shell script "cd " & quoted form of POSIX path of desktopFolder & "; ls"
```

Answer (score 0):

I eventually got it to work with this (provides a bunch of blank lines and stuff before the command executes, as well):

```
set filepath to POSIX path of (path to me)
set newpath to text 1 thru ((offset of "TextAdventure.app" in filepath) - 1) of filepath
do shell script "open /Applications/Utilities/Terminal.app"
tell application "Terminal"
    activate
    do script "cd \"" & newpath & "TextAdventure.app/Contents/Java/\""
    do script "echo \"


























 \"" in window 1
    do script "java Adventure" in window 1
end tell
```